# BreezeJS custom type not mapped correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breeze

This is a little mystifying to me.
I have a custom type defined on the client as such:

```
var store = manager.metadataStore;
store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "ItemContainer",
            autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
            dataProperties: {
                id: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },
                type: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isNullable: false },
                isViewed: { dataType: DataType.Boolean, isNullable: false },
                itemCount: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isNullable: false }
            }
        });

store.setEntityTypeForResourceName('Container', 'ItemContainer');
```

and this is what's passed from the server as an anonymous type (Fiddler):

```
[{"$id":"1","$type":"<>f__AnonymousType1`4[[System.Int32,mscorlib],
[System.Int32, mscorlib],
[System.Boolean, mscorlib],
[System.Int32, mscorlib]], XYZ",
"Id":43,"Type":1,"IsViewed":true,"ItemCount":19}]
```

When I examine the returned result on the client thru a breeze query, all the data is correct except the itemCount.  The server code generating the type looks like this:

```
var c = Items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Item.ItemTypeID, x.IsViewed })
                .Select(g => new { Id = ID, Type = g.Key.ItemTypeID, IsViewed = g.Key.IsViewed, ItemCount = g.Count() });
```

the g.Count() (LINQ Count Method) seems to be the culprit here.  If I pass a plain integer, it works just fine.  Maybe this function gets lazily evaluated, and breeze is not getting the value at the right time?

Thanks

Comment: What does the server side projection code look like?

Comment: I added the server code.  I fixed the issue for now by sending JSON and parsing it on the client (removed the custom entity type on the client).  But I'm still curious as to why this doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, can't repro. ...